# Cannot resolve method 'query' in 'Neo4jOperations'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

pom.xml contains

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
    </dependency>
```

In service

```
private final Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations;
public GraphInitService(Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations) {
    this.neo4jOperations = neo4jOperations;
}
   private void execute(String query) {
    return neo4jOperations.query(query);
}
```

but am getting error as Cannot resolve method 'query' in 'Neo4jOperations'
Am I doing something wrong